# Link combo box and parallel array

Tags: c#

I need help linking or mapping a combo box to a parallel array in C#. I have a class project where I need to create a payroll system that displays the Net Pay after taxes.

I want to link parallel arrays that have all the employee information needed for payroll to the option selected in the combo box. I feel like I almost have it, but I don't know how to link the option selected from the combo box and the parallel arrays I have set up.

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace ZNSPayrollSystem
   {
       public partial class ZNSPayrollSystem : Form
       {

           public ZNSPayrollSystem()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                string[] arr = { "001 Peters", "002 Barnes", "003 Harris" };
                cboEmp.DataSource = arr.ToArray();

            }

            private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //parallel arrays         
                int[] empID = { 001, 002, 003 };
                string[] empName = { "James Peters", "Sarah Barnes", "Candice Harris" };
                double[] hrsWorked = { 40, 40, 40 };
                double[] empWage = { 55.50, 65.50, 75.70 };

                //declarations
                double dblTaxRate = 8.2 / 100;
                double dblNetPay;
                double dblGrossPay;
                double dblTaxWithheld;

                dblGrossPay = hrsWorked[] * empWage[];
                dblTaxWithheld = dblGrossPay * dblTaxRate;
                dblNetPay = dblGrossPay - dblTaxWithheld;

                txtGross.Text = dblGrossPay.ToString();
                txtTax.Text = dblTaxWithheld.ToString();
                txtNetPay.Text = dblNetPay.ToString();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off creating an `Employee` class that had properties for ID, Name, hours, and wage? And then having an array or `List<Employee>` of those? It would allow you to keep all of the employee data together instead of having to mess with 4 different arrays.

Comment: @itsme86 is a class/homework assignment.  Probably have not gotten to objects or lists yet.

Comment: @itsme86 Thanks for your answers, and ya Trisped is right, we haven't learned how to do that in class yet. I'll look through my book and see if I can learn how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `SelectedIndex` property of the `Combobox`:

```
int i = cboEmp.SelectedIndex;

if (i != -1)
{
    dblGrossPay = hrsWorked[i] * empWage[i];
}
```

`i == -1` means nothing is selected. You may want to handle this separately to avoid getting any exceptions.

Comment: Precisely! - Just don't forget to add a conditional ensuring i > -1 (if nothing is selected).

Comment: @Sergey SlepovThanks, this looks like exactly what I needed. I knew it was something simple i just overlooked. That got rid of all the errors, but when i ran the program nothing would pop up in the text boxes when I clicked the Calc button. Now I have to figure out how to fix that. Thanks for the swift answer though.